# Dismiss html dialog element by clicking the backdrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the material design lite library to create [dialogs](https://getmdl.io/components/#dialog-section), which essentially uses the underlying [`<dialog>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) element, is there any way to dismiss the dialog by clicking on its backdrop? (When clicking the dialog contents themselves it should *not* be dismissed).

```
<dialog>Hi</dialog>    
<button>show</button>

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",
  () => document.querySelector("dialog").showModal());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fyjbvbqq/

Clicking anywhere on the screen when the dialog is shown corresponds to clicking the `dialog` element so it seems like there is no simple way to determine if the backdrop was clicked ... is there a way to do this?

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25864259

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the [Element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get size and position of the dialog and test if the current client coordinates are inside this area:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => document.querySelector("dialog").showModal());
document.querySelector("dialog").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var minX = rect.left + e.target.clientLeft;
  var minY = rect.top + e.target.clientTop;
  if ((e.clientX < minX || e.clientX >= minX + e.target.clientWidth) ||
      (e.clientY < minY || e.clientY >= minY + e.target.clientHeight)) {
    e.target.close();
  }
});
```

```html
<dialog>Hi</dialog>

<button>
    show
</button>
```

Comment: This is pretty close, but I think I want the opposite of this logic (clicking the backdrop dismisses; when I run your snippet I have to click the dialog itself to dismiss it)

Comment: @ExplosionPills Fixed. Sorry for my english, I understood exactly the opposite. Now, only clicking outside, the dialog will be dissmissed.

Comment: Thanks! the only issue I see is that the bounding box border can also be clicked to dismiss the modal, but this isn't a big deal. Just wondering if there is an easy way to handle that

Answer (score 4):

A current succinct way of handling this problem is:

```
dialog.addEventListener('click', ({target:dialog}) => {
    if (dialog.nodeName === 'DIALOG') {
        dialog.close('dismiss');
    }
});
```

This works because clicks inside the dialog itself will have the nodeName of the dialog content (e.g. `P`, `FORM`, etc.), whereas clicks on the backdrop will have the nodeName of `DIALOG`.

Source: "[Adding Light Dismiss](https://web.dev/building-a-dialog-component/#adding-light-dismiss)" on web.dev