How to stop mouse events through CSS ::backdrop
I'm exploring replacing some JavaScript modals with native HTML and CSS only modals using the new Popover API and I've noticed that pointer-events like hover and click are propagating through to the underlying layer.


::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(40%) blur(3px);
}
    <button popovertarget="mypopover" popovertargetaction="show">
      Show popover
    </button>
    <div id="mypopover" popover>Popover content</div>
    
    <a href="https://google.com"/>Links</a>



How can I prevent clicks propagating to underlying layer elements when the ::backdrop is being shown? I've attempted pointer-events: none but seen no success.
If it's not currently possible, are there browser bugs to follow for tracking this functionality?

This can be partially solved with the <dialog> element, but it requires JS to open and close, and cannot be closed by clicking on the ::backdrop without JS workarounds:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/25864259/312369

You may also try to filter popover-open and reset pointer-events on a few elements :
CSS idea is:


::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(40%) blur(3px);
}

/* filter element not supposed to catch mouse events */
body:has(:popover-open) :is(button, a) {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* then allow click from #mypopover */
#mypopover :is(button, a) {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
<button popovertarget="mypopover" popovertargetaction="show">
      Show popover
    </button>
<div id="mypopover" popover>Popover content <a href="#">link in popover</a></div>

<a href="https://google.com" />Links</a>



Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:popover-open to find your own use
caniuse ? https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Apopover-open

Maybe this is a dirty option, but you can close the space with other elements in popover:


::backdrop {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(40%) blur(3px);
}

#mypopover {
  overflow: visible;
  i {
    position: absolute;
    &:first-child {
      inset: -100vmax -100vmax 100%;
    }
    &:last-child {
      inset: 100% -100vmax -100vmax;
    }
  }
  &:before,
  &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
  }
  &:before {
    inset: 0 100% 0 -100vmax;
  }
  &:after {
    inset: 0 -100vmax 0 100%;
  }
}
<button popovertarget="mypopover" popovertargetaction="show">
  Show popover
</button>
<div id="mypopover" popover><i></i>Popover content<i></i></div>

<a href="https://google.com"/>Links</a>




That solves being able to interact with elements behind the backdrop. But it's no longer possible to close the popover by clicking on the backdrop. I suppose it works though if you ensure every modal always has a "Close" button inside itself.

I thought that was what you were after
